# Jenkins groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: catchError()

Tags: jenkins, groovy, junit, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using Jenkins `catchError` from Pipeline: Basic Steps (https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#catcherror-catch-error-and-set-build-result-to-failure) in my groovy file. 
I'm using it instead of a try/catch because I want to set a stageResult. However, I can't pass my test which gives the error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: catchError() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap...
```

My code looks like this:

```
def npmAudit(Map args) {
    catchError (buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'UNSTABLE', message: 'vulnerabilities from npm'){

        sh "npm audit"
        sh "touch audit.done"
    }
}
```

My Test is the below. I tried to add a assertMethodArgsList for the catchError which is commented out below, but that didn't work. The catchError method works fine in the code, but fails in the test.

```
@Test
void should_stage_npm_audit() throws Exception {
    npmAudit

    //assertMethodArgsList('catchError', 3, [
        //buildResult: 'SUCCESS',
        //stageResult: 'UNSTABLE',
        //message: 'message'
    //])

    assertMethodArgsList('sh', 2, [
        "npm audit",
        "touch audit.done"
    ])
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your pipeline, please?

Answer (score 1):

catcherror with params introduced in version 2.16 of workflow plugin. Update should fix the error

Comment: Do you know the name of the specific plugin. It says workflow plugin is renamed Pipeline plugin, which I have running at version 2.6. My jenkins version is at 2.225

Comment: Ah I found it, I am running 2.18 and upgraded to 2.19